# javascript remote rule not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

Hi I'm doing a validation form. I use codeigniter so I do of course a first validation with php.

I have a .js file to validate the form too. The thing is that some changes were made and now the file is no longer working properly.

When a field passes validation, a green icon appears next to the field. When it doesn't then the input box appears in red.

A field that is not working is documentn. I made a function to check if the document is already on the database. It worked on the past, now I can't figure out why is not working.

This is a snippet from the file:

```
form2.validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            ignore: "",
            onfocusout: function (element) {
                $(element).valid();
            },               
            rules: {
                documentn: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 7,
                    maxlength: 20,
                    digits: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: '/checkDocNumber',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            documentn: function(){
                                var dn = $('#documentn').val();
                                $("#documentn").removeData("previousValue");
                                return dn;
                            }  

                        } 
                    } 
                },
```

this is snippet from my admin.php:

```
public function updateFrontUser(){
    $result = array();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->database();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('documentn', 'Nro de Documento', 'required|min_length[7]|max_length[20]|is_natural');
```

this is function to check if document already exists on the database:

```
public function checkDocNumber(){
    if (isset($_POST['documentn'])){            
        $dn = UserManager::getInstance()->getByDocument($_POST['documentn']);
        if ($dn){
            echo "true";
        }else{              
            echo "false";
        }
    }  
}
```

how can I check if data from remote rule is being passed to my checkDocNumber function?

**EDIT**

when I do a browser inspection no error appears!

Comment: This is very close to a good question, you just need to add one piece of information:  When you get the error about `Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`, click the down arrow beside it, and see the call stack.  That should tell you what library/function call actually was being made when the error was generated.

Comment: @Ryley Hey, right now I'm not having any errors shown when inspecting. I fixed one error but the field document is still not working... which is weird because no js error appears now. I'll edit that part from my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. Just changed url from checkDocNumber to /admin/checkDocNumber

Still can't understand why it worked before with url being just checkDocNumber.

```
documentn: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 7,
     maxlength: 20,
     digits: true,
     remote: {
         url: '/admin/checkDocNumber',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {
             documentn: function(){
                var dn = $('#documentn').val();
                $("#documentn").removeData("previousValue");
                return dn;
             }  
         } 
  } 
},
```